# Strange bug in table

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm in Coldfusion 8. I have a table that is produced by a loop.  Very complex code but I put some of it here:

```
    <cfloop array = #qrep.getColumnList()# index = "col">                   
        <cfset l = l + 1> 
    <cfif l EQ tindx - 1>
    <cfset prevcol= col>
    </cfif>
     <cfif linefold GT 0>
           <cfset lmod = i%linefold>
           <cfelse>
           <cfset lmod = 1>
           </cfif>
        <!--- printing detail ---> 
        <cfif l LE m AND repdetail NEQ 'n'> 

        <td class = "repsubthead"> Subtotal: 
         <b>#qrep[col][currentrow]#</b></td>
        </cfif>

       <!--- printing totals only; row labels --->
       <cfif repdetail EQ 'n' AND l EQ tindx > 

       <cfset frowarr[footrow] = qrep[col][currentrow]>              
       <cfset footrow_1 = footrow - 1>               

              <cfif footrow EQ 1>
              <td style = "font-size: 13px" > #qrep[col][currentrow]#</td>                   
              <cfelseif frowarr[footrow] NEQ frowarr[footrow_1]  >
              <td style = "font-size: 13px;"> #qrep[col]currentrow]#</td>                    
              <cfelse>
              <cfset testrow = footrow>
              <td class = "repsubthead" style = "padding-top: 10px"> Total #qrep[prevcol] currentrow]# </td>              
              </cfif> 
       .... lots more before we get to end of loop
```

This part of the code prints out a row label for each row.  Further in the program there is a similar loop to print out the value for the row.  Everything is working fine except for one problem I can't trace. An extra row is being inserted in one spot, with no data in it.  Part of the table is here:

```
State:   CT  
AVS             25.00
COMB            15.00
Email2010       15.00
REF             75.00
STRLST01        22.00
  extra row inserted here, height much smaller than other rows
STRLST04        50.00
Total CT       202.00
```

I have copied this table to a Libre Office document and zoomed in on the bad row.  It is definitely there, and it contains a blinking item that looks like this: '

I cannot delete this item from the row in Libre Office, although I am able to delete the entire row.  The blinking thing disappears when I put my cursor in another row.

I have checked both STRLST01 and STRLST04 in my MySQL database, and they seem fine, with no anomalies.  I cannot find anywhere in my code where I would be inserting an extra row (altho admittedly the code is very complicated).

Has anyone seen something like this?  Does anyone have a clue what might be causing this?

Comment: I don't know what is causing it, but you might be able to achieve what you need with more simplicity and less code if you used cfoutput query="your query" group="one of the fields"

Comment: The code you've posted has at least two syntax errors which prevent it from compiling. **Read [sscce.org](http://sscce.org)** then update your example code accordingly.

Comment: (Off topic, will delete when acknowledged): @PeterBoughton, great article link. Hope you don't mind I co-opted it for a blog article: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Comment: \*shrug\* Not a problem. I think I originally saw that link elsewhere on SO, but it was a while back and don't remember for sure.

Comment: Start by examining the value of `qrep[col][currentrow]` when the extra row is generated. Examine it character by character if needed. That will help you figure out whether the extra row is generated by the data or the cfml/html code.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark here... but try sanitizing your table content.  For example:

```
#htmlEditFormat(qrep[col][currentrow])#
```

This would be to rule out that the TR in "STRLST01" isn't getting processed as `<TR>`.  I've seen dynamic tables like this one go haywire because the content gets interpreted as HTML.

MC

Answer (score 0):

What is the generated HTML? Looking at the actual generated output rather than the rendered output could help you find if it's bad data being dumped into another row or if it's a bug in your HTML generation routine.

If it's an odd special character in your data, the HTMLEditFormat() or XMLFormat() functions should find it and deal with it. Or at least make it easier to troubleshoot.